# Filtrar uma matriz javascript dinamicamente utilizando o for

Tags: javascript, ionic, typescript, ionic3

Preciso construir um filtro em uma lista, acontece que estou com problema pelo fato dos comparativos serem dinâmicos. Basicamente eu preciso dar ao usuário a condição de filtrar por, várias condições de pagamento por exemplo: 'cheque' e 'dinheiro', então me retorna tudo que tem cheque e dinheiro.

Para montar as opções de filtro eu utilizo simplesmente um push, onde crio o objeto chamado filtrosRealizados, e monto o array dentro deste objeto, o array seria condicaoPgto:

```
this.filtrosRealizados.condicaoPgto.push(condicaoPgto);
```

Depois disso na tela em que os filtros serão executados, eu uso um for para percorrer, recebendo o objeto criado anteriormente por parâmetro:

```
 modalEscolherFiltros.onWillDismiss((data => {
  if (data != undefined || data != null) {
    let condicoesPgto: any;
    condicoesPgto = data.condicaoPgto;
    console.log(this.financeiroRealizado);

    for (let i = 0; i < this.financeiroRealizado.length; i++) {
      this.financeiroRealizado = this.financeiroRealizado.filter((result: any) =>
        result.condicaoPagamento == condicoesPgto[i]
      );
    }
    console.log(this.financeiroRealizado);
  } else {
    console.log('nao tem parametro');
  }
}))
```

Então eu faço o filter na minha matriz, e digo que quero que result.condicaoPagamento (que são as condições de pagamento que tenho na matriz) seja igual as condições de pagamento que recebi por parâmetro. O resultado que espero é que me retorne a lista com as condições de pagamento que filtrei, porém estou recebendo uma lista vazia.

Atualizando: No console.log eu não consigo obter os dois filtro escolhidos na tela anterior, quando faço console.log na na variável condicoesPgto, ele me retorna apenas a primeira condição de pagamento, então acredito que é ai que está o problema, porém não entendo porque disso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Fazendo um simples teste, ao invés de chamar condicoesPgto[i], eu chamei 'Dinheiro' e me retorna como o esperado, porém eu gostaria que isso fosse dinâmico

Comment: Se colocando o filtro direto funcionou, como estão os dados da variável condicoesPgto? Estão corretos? Colocando um console.log dela, está com os valores que você esperava?

Comment: Não, ele retorna apenas a primeira condição de pagamento. Adicionei uma imagem com o console.log. Neste caso ele não retorna a condição de pagamento débito, porém deveria funcionar mesmo assim com dinheiro eu acho.